# Android resource linking failed - How to solve it?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-icons, android-asset-studio

I recently changed the icon of my app. **When I run the app using USB debugging on my phone, everything is fine**, the app compiles and the icon is as it should be. But as soon as **I try to generate a signed APK, the compilation ends with this error**:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
>
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Adam\AndroidStudioProjects\Generator\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher not found.

Which is strange because otherwise everything works and the xml file is where it's supposed to be. I created the icons using **Image Asset** and they generated correctly. The only thing that comes to me as a possible cause is that for ic_launcher there is **only an xml file, but ic_launcher_round has a whole folder with png images** as well. Also, in the manifest there is a preview of the icon only **for the round version, it is not loaded for the regular version**:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was enough to select the icon as ***res directory:* main** when confirming the path:

[image]

Comment: hello, i am having thesame error but i cant understand what u said here

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga When you open Vector Asset Studio, fill in the "Configure Vector Asset" section and set the Source set: main in the "Confirm Icon Path" section. Follow the same procedure for Image Asset Studio. I also added a picture, hope it helps.